# Why are my baked textures different from my original?

Tags: shaders

[image]

I have two models of bread. On the left I have my original model. On the right I have my baked model.

I am curious to know why the baked model looks different to the original. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were alot of different issues which caused the baked textures to look different from the original.

**Here is a list of all the problems that I encountered (+ a few more which I thought might be useful to list):**

- The models need to be exactly overlapping each other to bake correctly. Not doing this will cause the bake's to be black. Using *Alt + G* will reset the location of the two models.
- Often when trying to compare the two bakes, you might choose to flip the model - scaling it by -1 on the x-axis. Ensure that this is reset before attempting to rebake the models. *Alt + S* will reset the scale of the two models.
- Some people advocate for a multiresolution bake. In the case of the bread model above, multiresolution baking significantly dropped the quality of the image. This method is significantly inferior to just simply baking a *normal* map and a *diffuse* map because it synthesizes new *normal* information instead of using the high detailed normal information of the original.

[image]

- Ensure the low poly model is UV unwrapped. Failing to do so will immediately break the tiling.
- Ensure your metallic slider is set to `0.000` for the bake. Failing to do so will result in a black bake.

Answer (score 1):

Your high-poly has a normal map that creates these small bumps and details, but it looks like you didn't bake it, therefore the difference between the high-poly and the low-poly:

[image]

For some reason the diffuse maps don't align either, bake it as well. When baking, put your 2 objects are at the same location. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I referred to your solution with mixRGB but it does not appear to work well when the position of the normals matters (such as the having specific positions for the breadcrumbs). I'm trying to think of other ways to get the mapping correct but none immediately come to mind :(

Comment: I'm failing to understand how setting baketype to diffuse yields a normal map... I tried baking with baketype to normal. That worked and gave me the high detail normal map with correct uv islands. However, the breadcrumb normals still dont align in the low poly version

Comment: oops you're right you can simply bake the normals, but what do you mean when you say that the breadcrumb don't align? It looks like you also need to bake the Diffuse again, for some reason the current Diffuse map is not good

Comment: Edit: ok it works fine, I didn't know you could bake both the real bumps and the normal map of a high-poly onto a low-poly, but you also need to rebake the Diffuse of your high-poly, for some reason it was not correct. Don't forget to put the 2 objects at the same position when you bake. Tell me if it's ok

Comment: i believe i've worked out all the issues. Im going to write up an answer which describes every problem I've had during this process. Thank you for the help, i really appreciate it @moonboots